# Android editText.setError is not visible fully if i use NoTitleBar theme

Tags: android, android-edittext, titlebar

I am facing different issue related to editText.setError.
if i use `android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"` in my application, the error messages are not completely visible.if i remove error messages are visible correctly.

with no title bar
http://postimg.org/image/53033ykqh/

without no title bar
http://postimg.org/image/kn7guhuux/

Please help me to fix this issue.

Comment: put this `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"` in your activity in android manifest

Answer (score 0):

put this `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"` in your activity in Android Manifest 
[more Details](http://blog.vogella.com/2010/10/25/android-windowsoftinputmode/)

Comment: hey, did you try the answer i posted?